# how do i make my required textfield work first and then the onclick

Tags: html

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtSpouseOccupation" id="txtSpouseOccupation" required>
<button type="button" id="next_personal" class="form-control btn-success" style="width:10%" onclick="openTab(event,'dependentTab')">Next</button>
```

when I click the next button it just goes to the next tab and ignores the required even the inputs are not yet filled up

Comment: Please paste the `function()` code also.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish your need by using this simple attribute **required**. So below I'll add example;

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="next.php">
        <input type="text" required="true">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So when you click button to navigate to next page or tab it will show simple message near relevant text box to fill that field.
Though you used tabs you can use this.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your both elements are independent to each other. You have `text/input` whose functionality is to take inputs and then there is a `submit button` whose functionality to do something on click.

Now `required` will only work if you define a relation between `submit button` and `input/text`. `<form>` elements does that for you as it wraps both elements in it and than the `submit` `button` default action is to submit the form, and then before submitting it will check if the input values are assigned as per `required=true`.

But you trigger a function on the click of it. If you simply want to go to some `url` by submitting `form`

Try `Form`

```html
<form action="your url" method="GET or POST">
  <input type= "text" required ="true"/>
  <button type = "submit" >next</button>
</form>
```

OR you can use `javascript` for it.

```js
function newTab(){
  let input = document.getElementById('text-input').value;
  if(input === ""){
    alert('please fill text')
    return;
   }
   window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
}
```

```html
  <input type= "text" required ="true" id = "text-input"/>
  <button type = "submit" onClick = "newTab()" >next</button>
```

Comment: how do i redirect it to a tab instead of a website? the code is like this openTab(event,'licencesTab');